# How to change my current location using Python requests?

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-requests, geolocation

I'm trying to scrape Amazon Singapore's seller quantity. To do that, I was using VPN service which connected to Singapore server. But I don't want to use it anymore because it's free use time expired. Instead of using VPN, I want to change my location using `requests` library.

Here's my code:

```
# Set asin, link and headers
asin = XXXXXXXXXX
link = 'https://www.amazon.sg/dp/' + str(asin)

# Headers
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

# Set requests object
res = requests.get(link, params = {"format": "json"}, headers = headers)

# Create soup object
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup_data)
```

When I run this code, Amazon sees me in Turkey (which is my current location). And I can't see how many people are selling the product because of Amazon sees me in Turkey. I want to change my location to Singapore. How can I do this with `requests` library or changing `headers`?

Does Amazon have a `GET` parameters to change the location? Such as:

```
www.amazon.sg/dp/ASIN_NUMBER?LOCATION=SINGAPORE
```

Hope you guys understand what I meant.

Comment: It is very unlikely that Amazon will allow your client to tell it where it is. It is much more likely that Amazon use your IP address (and maybe other factors) to decide where it thinks you are. By using a VPN you are changing the IP that Amazon sees you connecting from, hence changing the location they think you are in.

Comment: You might want to use residential proxy to hide your location as Singapore. Scraping is usually being blocked in marketplace. A normal VPN could not defeat the scraper detection in Amazon. There are ready solution such as IP2Proxy to detect data center, VPN and scraper.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon is probably using your IP to determine your location. You could try to use some publicly available proxies:

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://d.pub.network/init"

    for address in ("http://45.77.151.33:8080", "http://136.244.83.131:8080"):
        proxies = {
            "https": address
        }
        
        response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
        content = response.json()

        city = content["location"]["cityName"]
        country = content["location"]["countryCode"]

        print("I think you are in {}, {}".format(city, country))
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
I think you are in Piscataway, US
I think you are in Frankfurt am Main, DE
>>>
```

Comment: How can I show myself to Amazon as if I am in Singapore with this code? I tried few things but it keeps crashing.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that Amazon will allow your client to tell it where it is. It is much more likely that Amazon use your IP address (and maybe other factors) to decide where it thinks you are. By using a VPN you are changing the IP that Amazon sees you connecting from, hence changing the location they think you are in.

Comment: Yes sir. That's the reason why I used to use VPN. Amazon use my IP address to decide where I am. But as I said, I couldn't find a free VPN with a Singapore server. So I want to get this done using Python. If I can't handle this with Python, can you tell me a free VPN with a Singapore server?